# Simple Core Data query

Tags: ios, core-data, database-design

I'm designing a chat application for iOS and I have built the model (any feedback would be appreciated...) which is below, but I'm not sure it's fit for purpose.

[image]

As per the model above, when I create a new conversation, the sender and receiver would be added to the participant set.

Now when I come to build my master table view, I would like to display only receiver participants (exactly like iMessage does - see picture below), but can't think how to extract only the receivers.

[image]

I did think about adding a "to" and "from" in the Conversation entity but that feels slightly clunky?.  And whilst having the participants feels a little cleaner, I still can't come up with a simple solution.

My initial thought was to get all conversations and exclude the mainUser (who would be the sender)

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Conversation"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY participants.mainUser == nil"]];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:NO];
```

But that doesn't work because I'm asking for the Conversation which includes both participants.

Maybe there is a design issue here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried in vain to solve this exact same problem. After wasting a lot of time discovering that it couldn't be done with any kind of CoreData query, I ended up creating a table just for message headers. So you might want to consider trying something like this:

```
Table: MessageHeader
Attributes:  
latestMessageTimeStamp  
Relationships:  
Message   
User
```

MessageHeader contains one row for each user the current user has received a message from, or sent a message to. So you basically maintain a single row in MessageHeader for each contact the current user has corresponded with. The attribute latestMessageTimeStamp is updated whenever a message is received from or sent to that contact. Also, you would need to update that timestamp if messages are deleted, or even delete the whole row if deleting the last and only message to/from a given contact.